# Pandas "update" method is not doing anything

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two dataframes, a large one (df1) and a smaller one (df2). Both have the same columns and indexes.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(milkProdFile, delimiter=';', dtype=str, names=cols).set_index(["ANIM", "NULACT"], drop=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv(correctionFile, delimiter=';', dtype=str, names=cols).set_index(["ANIM", "NULACT"], drop=False)
```

I wish to replace the rows from the large dataframe df1 with the matching rows (meaning the rows with matching indexes) from the small dataframe df2 using the update method from pandas.

```
df1.update(df2)
df1.to_csv("./corrected_lacts.txt", sep=';', header=False, index=False)
```

However, after executing this code, nothing happened. The corrected_lacts.txt text file still has the original values contained in the milkProdFile used to create df1.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it ?

EDIT : 
vladislavAks' answer did the trick. I moved the `set_index` to the end of my code and it worked. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Without data, it's difficult to help you because your code should work.

Comment: This code should basically work, unless there is no match indicies between two dfs. Be sure that the combination of "ANIM" and "NULACT" columns have mathing rows in two dfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `.set_index` after update. I tried this code with example data, and it works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ANIM': [1, 2, 3],
               'NULACT': [400, 500, 600], 
              'target': [1, 1, 1]}) # without ".set_index(["ANIM", "NULACT"], drop=False)"

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'ANIM': [4, 5, 6],
                   'NULACT': [7, 8, 9], 
                  'target': [0, 1, 0]})

df.update(new_df)
df.set_index(["ANIM", "NULACT"], drop=False)
```

Comment: Will try, thanks !

Comment: i dont understand why this would work. how does the update know what you consider a matching row if you dont set the index before?